# Flexslider IE8 caption text not fading

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, fade, flexslider

I have a FlexSlider (new version) with fade effect between each slide.

The slider works correctly in all browsers apart from IE<=8. In IE8 the images are fading nicely but the text in the captions is not being faded resulting in a weird instant change between slide 1-2, 2-3 and so on...

I tried looking for a fix but couldn't find anything useful and working, is there a solution for this out there?

Thank you in advance,
bye.

Here is a little JSFiddle that is showing the problem in IE8
http://jsfiddle.net/VpD7L/3/

Comment: You're not giving us much to work with. Can you share with us an example of your code ore demo of the slider so that we can troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After struggling many hours to find out why the text wasn't fading I've found out that the problem is IE8 not liking position:absolute (or relative) and z-index on flex slider text container.
So i've used padding instead to position my texts.

Maybe this will be useful in future for someone.

Comment: This fixed it for me - thanks for answering your own question!

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this before. It may be that some element or another that you're working with doesn't have "layout" applied, or an element does have layout when it needs to not have it.

The first thing to do is start applying / resetting haslayout from the elements involved. The most likely scenario is that the text itself needs to have hasLayout applied to its containing element.

From here: http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

> The following CSS property/value pairs will, if applied, allow an
> element to gain layout.
>
> position: absolute
> float: left|right
> display: inline-block
> width: any value other than 'auto'
> height: any value other than 'auto'
> zoom: any value other than 'normal' (MSDN)
> writing-mode: tb-rl (MSDN)
> overflow: hidden|scroll|auto
> overflow-x|-y: hidden|scroll|auto
> position: fixed
> min-width: any value
> max-width: any value other than 'none'
> min-height: any value
> max-height: any value other than 'none'
>
> Resetting the following properties to their default value in a
> separate rule set will reset (or undo) hasLayout, if no other property
> giving hasLayout remains in effect:
>
> width, height (to 'auto')
>
> max-width, max-height (to 'none') (in IE 7)
>
> position (to 'static')
>
> float (to 'none') overflow (to 'visible') (in IE 7)
>
> zoom (to 'normal')
>
> writing-mode (from 'tb-rl' to 'lr-tb')

You can use Microsoft's web developer toolbar to check whether or not your elements have layout (if they don't, hasLayout will be -1 in the developer toolbar, and 1 if they do).

Comment: thank you for your effort but this just doesn't seem the case...I'll keep try and see if I can get over it.